# Sorting values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, python-3.6

I've been trying to sort the values on my a `dataframe` that I've been given to work on.

The following is my `dataframe`.

```
1981    1.78
1982    1.74
1983    1.61
1984    1.62
1985    1.61
1986    1.43
1987    1.62
1988    1.96
1989    1.75
1990    1.83
1991    1.73
1992    1.72
1993    1.74
1994    1.71
1995    1.67
1996    1.66
1997    1.61
1998    1.48
1999    1.47
2000     1.6
2001    1.41
2002    1.37
2003    1.27
2004    1.26
2005    1.26
2006    1.28
2007    1.29
2008    1.28
2009    1.22
2010    1.15
2011     1.2
2012    1.29
2013    1.19
2014    1.25
2015    1.24
2016     1.2
2017    1.16
2018    1.14
```

I've been trying to sort my `dataframe` in descending order such that the highest values on the right would appear first. However whenever I try to sort it, it would only sort based on the year which are the values on the left.

```
dataframe.sort_values('1')
```

I've tried using sort_values and indicating '1' as the column that I want sorted. This however returns `ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: Because the first argument will be taken as `by`. You need to use the `axis` keyword

Answer (score 1):

From the error that OP mentioned, The data structure is a Series and hence the sort function should just be called directly

```
s = s.sort_values(ascending=False)
```

The error was raised because, in `pandas.Series.sort_values` the first argument is axis.

Answer (score 0):

The argument of `sort_values()` should be column name:

```py
df=df.sort_values("col2")
```